# rails7にてstripeイベントをwebhock間でデータを送受信して決済情報を反映させたい。

Tags: ruby-on-rails

railsでwebhockを使用してstripeにイベントを送受信したいのですがエラーが発生して上手くいきません。

✳︎ エラー内容

```
023-12-05 23:06:06   --> charge.succeeded [evt_3OJzGCLxspDGl3kt1UhDraJD]
2023-12-05 23:06:06  <--  [204] POST http://localhost:8000/webhooks [evt_3OJzGCLxspDGl3kt1UhDraJD]
2023-12-05 23:06:06   --> payment_intent.succeeded [evt_3OJzGCLxspDGl3kt1P3XV3JA]
2023-12-05 23:06:06  <--  [204] POST http://localhost:8000/webhooks [evt_3OJzGCLxspDGl3kt1P3XV3JA]
2023-12-05 23:06:06   --> payment_intent.created [evt_3OJzGCLxspDGl3kt1xMx1E3q]
2023-12-05 23:06:06  <--  [204] POST http://localhost:8000/webhooks [evt_3OJzGCLxspDGl3kt1xMx1E3q]
2023-12-05 23:06:06   --> checkout.session.completed [evt_1OJzGELxspDGl3ktI4oxRxzi]
2023-12-05 23:06:07  <--  [500] POST http://localhost:8000/webhooks [evt_1OJzGELxspDGl3ktI4oxRxzi]
```

調べたところ500 internal server errorと言って内部サーバー間のエラー?だとでできました。

ちなみにwebhocks_controller.rbのcreateのみを送受信しているのですが、作成アプリでカートに商品を入れてstripeで支払いを完了させると数量や在庫が変わってないといけないのに、webhockのイベントが送受信できないのでこちらの方に反映されておりません。

Webhooks_controller.rb

```
class Customer::WebhooksController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  
    def create
      payload = request.body.read
      sig_header = request.env['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE']
      endpoint_secret = Rails.application.credentials.dig(:stripe, :endpoint_secret)
      event = nil
  
      begin
        event = Stripe::Webhook.construct_event(
          payload, sig_header, endpoint_secret
        )
      rescue JSON::ParserError => e
        # Invalid payload
        p e
        status 400
        return
      rescue Stripe::SignatureVerificationError => e
        # Invalid signature
        p e
        status 400
        return
      end
  
      case event.type
      when 'checkout.session.completed'
        # ... execute a process
        session = event.data.object # sessionの取得
        customer = Customer.find(session.client_reference_id)
        return unless customer # 顧客が存在するかどうか確認
      
       # トランザクション処理開始
      ApplicationRecord.transaction do
        order = create_order(session) # sessionを元にordersテーブルにデータを挿入
        session_with_expand = Stripe::Checkout::Session.retrieve({ id: session.id, expand: ['line_items'] })
        session_with_expand.line_items.data.each do |line_item|
         create_order_details(order, line_item) # 取り出したline_itemをorder_detailsテーブルに登録
         end
      end
       # トランザクション処理終了
        customer.cart_items.destroy_all # 顧客のカート内商品を全て削除
        redirect_to session.success_url
      end
    end

    private

    def create_order(session)
      Order.create!({
                      customer_id: session.client_reference_id,
                      name: session.shipping.name,
                      postal_code: session.shipping.address.postal_code,
                      prefecture: session.shipping.address.state,
                      address1: session.shipping.address.line1,
                      address2: session.shipping.address.line2,
                      postage: session.shipping_options[0].shipping_amount,
                      billing_amount: session.amount_total,
                      status: 'confirm_payment'
                    })
    end

    def create_order_details(order, line_item)
           product = Stripe::Product.retrieve(line_item.price.product)
           purchased_product = Product.find(product.metadata.product_id)
           raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if purchased_product.nil?
        
           order_detail = order.order_details.create!({
                                                        product_id: purchased_product.id,
                                                        price: line_item.price.unit_amount,
                                                        quantity: line_item.quantity
                                                      })
           purchased_product.update!(stock: (purchased_product.stock - order_detail.quantity)) # 購入された商品の在庫数の更新                                        
   end
end
```

コントローラーで記述ミスがないかも確認しましたが特に分からずこのエラーの解決方法が分かりません。
どなたか詳しい方がおられましたらご教授お願いします。